# Primefaces intelligently finds dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ajax4jsf

How can this work:

```
<h:form id="newForm">
<p:dialog header="x" widgetVar="newDialog" id="newDlg" modal="true">
...
  <p:commandButton value="Close" update=":form1:dt1" id="cancelNew" immediate="true">
      <f:ajax event="click" onevent="xyz.hide()" />
  </p:commandButton>
```

`onevent` refers to a name which doesn't exist; yet, when I click the button, the dialog gets closed. If I omit the ajax-element, it doesn't close. Is this some PF (4) black magic?

Comment: No magic here. If it's not there, it's not there. Look in the source of the generated HTML to see what the generated onclick markup is. I'm  pretty sure it's still `xyz.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you omit `onevent` the `update` just runs and you go to `:form1:dt1`. Everything is ok with this and the dialog closes as it should do (because of the `update`). But when you have `onevent` you get an exception (as far as I understand) and because of this exception the dialog remains open. If you check the log you should see the exception.

Inside the dialog should also a form exist like :

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="Dialog" .........  

         <h:form id="formDialog">  
              ...............
```

Comment: no, there is no exception. Also, when omitting the `update`, it also closes

Comment: I suppose all the elements exist e.g forms dialogs etc. Correct?

Comment: Also, I assume inside the dialog there is a tag with `form`.

Comment: I think is better to post the code of your page because the hierarchy of forms & dialogs play important role

Comment: I posted what is relevant. There are no additional forms